# How can I add A forgotten table to Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: entity-framework

I have created the entity framework from and existing database.  I missed a table when building the model and now need to get that table.  When I chose update model from database I do not see any available table.

Is there a way to add this table or do I need to delete the model and recreate it again?

Comment: Are you using DBFirst or CodeFirst starting from database?

Comment: Probably the table doesn't have a primary key. You can force to use that table (inventing a primary key) with CodeFirst but, if the problem is the primary key, with DbFirst you have to add the Pk.

Comment: No that is not the issue.  I did not bring the table into the entity framework when I built the model.  There were several table in the database that I did not need.  Unfortunately I missed this one table during the build and now can't seem to add it to my model